# Merge SSL certs - one with a proper CA and one self signed

Tags: ssl-certificate

As per the title - is this possible?

I have the scenario of some application running off Tomcat/Apache and in a customer environment, within the local LAN they are on the domain customer.local, and externally they own customer.com

However the same servers service both users in the LAN and externally, is it possible to combine a cert that I can load into the the Tomcat/Apache applications so that it will present validly for both internal and external resolution?
i.e. local LAN users will visit `https://application.customer.local` and external users will visit `https://application.customer.com`

Comment: It is "officially" impossible or even wise to have unrouteable (therefore uncheckable) CNs in one cert. Technically you can to that with a private CA, but no trusted CA will allow that. Search for "Multiple CNs" or "Multi-SAN" certificates. Merging multiple certs isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to merge certificates.

Just configure two virtual hosts on your server - one for `application.customer.local` and one for `application.customer.com`, each with their own certificate, but everything else such as web root in common.

I'm not aware that it's possible to merge or serve multiple certs for the same server.

Comment: was hoping there was some way to merge the certs ending up with something like multidomain certs. I'll look into virtual hosts, but i have no experience configuring the Tomcat/Apache services nor am I sure it's endorsed by the application vendor

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine existing certificates but you can generate a single new one with multiple [SANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name).

Comment: Although you can't get a cert for anything.local from a public CA, since you don't (uniquely) own it; you can get  a cert for both names from your own in-house CA, but external users probably won't -- and probably shouldn't -- trust your in-house CA.

Comment: True, but since using bogus DNS zones you do not own for your internal network is a bad idea, you should own your internal domain meaning you can do a DNS challenge to obtain a certificate for it. Given how frequently people feel compelled to obfuscate DNS names for no viable reason, the actual internal domain might be something better than the mDNS reserved .local...

Comment: thanks - i'm aware of how to generate my own certs and install it on external user devices.  Was trying to avoid this however by combining the certs. Would've been great if i could use the public CA signing on the .com domain (which the customer already has a proper cert for) in this process :) Would've like to accept this answer as well since it directly answers my question of whether i can combine certs but Stack only allows 1 accepted answer

Comment: Installing your internal CA to external devices is never the answer, "normal" users won't know how and corporate users won't be allowed to. I was pointing towards having a public CA sign a certificate for both domains but that means you need to truly own your internal domain which you always should. If you truly are on a .local domain for your LAN this answer doesn't apply.